# Sort the filter options in Shopify store

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm developing a Shopify site on the "Crave" theme.
Added a filter option along with the product's tag on the collection page. These filter options are sorted alphabetically. But here's the problem. Filter options sort incorrectly when tag names contain strings and numbers.
Like this;
tag's name-> "Number of guests: 10","Number of guests: 2", "Number of guests: 20", "Price:$100-$200", "Price:$200-$300", ...
How to align this properly?
I have attached an image file to demonstrate the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t06yP.png)

I tried rearranging the product tags in the tag management window. By the way, I can't find a function to sort product tag names.
There was also no ability to sort manually. Perhaps I'll have to program for that. Can you tell me how?